# How to iterate a values in the table including column headers and cells in Java Selenium to select a cell

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to click any cell value by matching title.The title can be present in any position. In this instance "Robert".

```
<div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" aria-selected="false" aria-readonly="true" aria-required="false" class="wj-cell" data-id="cell-0-4" id="Grid1271ed7b-3f36-d12c-803a-d560961d8724-id-cell-0-4" data-lp-id="MscrmControls.Grid.ReadOnlyGrid|entity_control|account|00000000-0000-0000-00aa-000010001210|contact|contact_customer_accounts|cc-grid|cc-grid-cell|cell-0-4" aria-colindex="4" title="---" style="left: 343px; top: 0px; width: 124px; height: 40px; padding-left: 7px !important; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 2px; padding-top: 2px; line-height: 35px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span role="presentation" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">---</span></div>
```

Robert
---

```html
    <div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" aria-selected="false" aria-readonly="true" aria-required="false" class="wj-cell" data-id="cell-0-4" id="Grid1271ed7b-3f36-d12c-803a-d560961d8724-id-cell-0-4" data-lp-id="MscrmControls.Grid.ReadOnlyGrid|entity_control|account|00000000-0000-0000-00aa-000010001210|contact|contact_customer_accounts|cc-grid|cc-grid-cell|cell-0-4" aria-colindex="4" title="---" style="left: 343px; top: 0px; width: 124px; height: 40px; padding-left: 7px !important; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 2px; padding-top: 2px; line-height: 35px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span role="presentation" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">---</span></div>
<div tabindex="0" role="gridcell" aria-selected="false" aria-readonly="true" aria-required="false" class="wj-cell" data-id="cell-0-2" id="Grid1271ed7b-3f36-d12c-803a-d560961d8724-id-cell-0-2" data-lp-id="MscrmControls.Grid.ReadOnlyGrid|entity_control|account|00000000-0000-0000-00aa-000010001210|contact|contact_customer_accounts|cc-grid|cc-grid-cell|cell-0-2" aria-colindex="2" title="Robert" style="left: 45px; top: 0px; width: 149px; height: 40px; padding-left: 7px !important; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 2px; padding-top: 2px; line-height: 35px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span role="presentation" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">Robert</span></div>
<div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" aria-selected="false" aria-readonly="true" aria-required="false" class="wj-cell" data-id="cell-0-4" id="Grid1271ed7b-3f36-d12c-803a-d560961d8724-id-cell-0-4" data-lp-id="MscrmControls.Grid.ReadOnlyGrid|entity_control|account|00000000-0000-0000-00aa-000010001210|contact|contact_customer_accounts|cc-grid|cc-grid-cell|cell-0-4" aria-colindex="4" title="---" style="left: 343px; top: 0px; width: 124px; height: 40px; padding-left: 7px !important; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 2px; padding-top: 2px; line-height: 35px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><span role="presentation" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">---</span></div>
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). You may like to consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: For starters, this is not an HTML table. This is an example of web elements (`divs`) formatted in a way that resemble a table. That said, if you are looking for something like "_return the cell value for the element in the nth row under "x" column header_", it is simply not possible. You will need to create locators that most will most likely need to rely on some criteria like column index. Your solution will require you being creative an clever to create reusable, parameterized locators (probably using Xpath).

Comment: The reason why I say it is not possible is because the DOM doesn't create this "grid" relationship between web elements. And traversing the DOM to establish relationships is not always feasible.

Comment: @hfontanez ...yes exactly thats what I was looking for. Thank you so much. Workaround , I Kind of parameterized  xpath for that specific column and matched the text to access the element for now.

Comment: @Fari edit your question and copy and paste the part of the DOM you need locators for as well as the code you wrote to process the locators.

Answer (score 1):

There is simply not enough information to precisely answer the question. So I will provide two general solutions. One of them should work.

### Working with `iframes`

It is possible your "table" is rendered inside an *iframe*. Elements contained within an iframe cannot be located unless your web driver is focusing on the iframe first. With Selenium, to switch to iframe you must do something like this to wait a maximum time of 10 seconds, polling every 100 milliseconds

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(x), Duration.ofMillis(100)); // Selenium 4.x 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(LOCATOR)));
```

If the above succeeds, you are ready to interact with the desired component. Of course, in the above snippet, *LOCATOR* is whichever type of locator you wish to use. For example, *`By.xpath("some_xpath_string_here")`*.

Once you are finished interacting with the components inside the iframe, you MUST switch out of it to interact with the components on the page. To do this, you instruct the driver to switch to the parent frame in the DOM.

```
driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
```

You must do this even if you refresh the current page or load a new one. Because of this, it is typically a good idea to put this inside a `finally` block.

### Locating the elements

Whether the elements you need to interact with are inside of an iframe or not, creating a strategy for locating elements on a page is not always trivial. For example, one of the easiest ways to locate components on a page is by *id*. The problem is that IDs are not always easy to predict. For example, in the OPs case, it seems like UUID is used to generate the ID. So, in this case, it is unlikely that locating by ID is an option. Although there are cases when obtaining multiple results is desirable, in this case, our locator should yield a single result. An XPath expression such as `//div[@tabindex=0]` (in this page) will locate at the moment of this post, 5 results. However, there is only one match inside the iframe. While testing this XPath expression using Chrome dev tools doesn't make this distinction, the WebDriver API does because this is how the specification is written. Therefore, if I switch to the iframe and then attempt to locate the table row with that given tab index, the code will only locate one. If we attempt the same without switching to the iframe, the code will locate 4 components, but will return the very first one it encountered in the DOM from the top of the document. In this case, that will be the question upvote/downvote count.

But, even though the XPath expression I created for this example is unique for the elements rendered inside the iframe, in a more realistic case it might be necessary to further refine out expression to match a more specific case. I believe in this case, that will be the name in the cell. Therefore, my refined expression should be `//div[@tabindex=0]/span[text()='Robert']`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean finding by the title or some text e.g //*[text()[contains(.,'Robert')]] or like //*[contains(@title, 'Robert')] to get the element?

Or to grab a particular cell that is nested above or below? - it may be possible to use some sort of selector using ancestor / descendant or to narrow in on the cell based on the particular text but like hfontanez says you will need to create selectors that rely on something like the title or some pattern to return the cell or grid row/column relative to where the title is in the DOM.

Comment: I just want to click on a First Name , say Robert in this case, this may appear in a different position next time, say in the above or below, depending on the table updates. So contains text with name is not working sometimes

Comment: @hfontanez also my answer was based on my interpretation of the question where he is asking how to select an element using the title. "I'm trying to click any cell value by matching title." hence my answer trying to help solve this with as I have mentioned limited access to interactions. I mentioned you as I agree with your comment but I don't have 50 reputation to join the comment thread and add that I agree with your answer.

Comment: @Fari could use a reference like anchor it on another element. e.g have a table and use the first field as a reference or the row in table and then search for the name or data relative to that. So like my cell {expected row} pass in the name as a parameter if you know where that will be relative to the row even if it will change chained onto the end of row. You can use as I mentioned above ancestor or parent if you know it will be within the nested grid structure so a descendant with that text anywhere underneath or above.

Comment: @Maire I understand all of that. I was just giving you advice. As you can see, I didn't downvote your answer because that's not how I operate. BUT, I have been around long enough to know how _others_ operate. I was just warning you.

Comment: @hfontanez - I appreciate it and thank you very much for the heads up! As soon as I have enough rep to avail of other features I will take this advice on board. I wasn't posting a guess either by the way - I meant like how OP could use * to find all references or similar to your answer some kind of anchor element - I'm just not the best at wording things sometimes but I'm working on it. I work with alot of tabular data and elements on getting data per cell or row and I took this as similar.